# Creating distribution IPA without giving access to an Apple Developer account

Tags: deployment, submit, release, ipa

My client is asking me to send an IPA build which can be sent to the Apple App store without giving me any access to the apple developer account, as he wants to submit the build himself.

As far as I know and researched, I need the account to set up the build, certificates, profiles, I cannot do this without having developer access to the Apple Developer account. If he would provide me with the certificates etc, even with those xCode would ask for the developer password of the account for validation.

I notified him of this, but they insist that this can be done.

Am I missing something? Basically he wants to do a submit of the IPA through Application Loader without giving me any access to Apple developer account.

Note: the app was developed with a different account.